# how to debug this lithium request?

Tags: code-coverage, lithium

I am trying to work on whats wrong with my lithium current setup. I have installed the Xdebug and verified that remote host can establish the connection as requested.

http://myinstance.com/test/lithium/tests/cases/analysis/logger/adapter/CacheTest?filters[]=lithium\test\filter\Coverage

Please note in fresh installation in local environment , "Coverage" Filter is working as expected.

I added some test code inside the "apply" function in coverage.php but it is not even called !!!! Can some have experience in debugging the above URL ?

I am not able to understand why coverage filter is not called up and executed ...Any hints are highly appreciated !

Comment: If someone know where this filters are getting invoke , I would like to know the exact point....

Comment: From access log - GET /test/lithium/tests/cases/analysis/logger/adapter/CacheTest?filters[]=lithium\x5Ctest\x5Cfilter\x5CCoverage ....is appending "x5C" is common??

Answer (score 0):

The filters in the query string are added to the options in `lithium\test\Controller::__invoke()` and then passed into the test `Report` object created by the test `Dispatcher`. The `Report` object finds the test filter class and then runs the `applyFilter()` method for that test filter as can be seen in [lines 140 to 143 of the current code](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/791c2ce345b63cd47f067cdebccb6497a35de014/test/Report.php#L140-L143). So those lines would be another place to debug. Those should wrap the `run()` method of your tests with [this filter code](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/791c2ce345b63cd47f067cdebccb6497a35de014/test/filter/Coverage.php#L44-L50) inside the `apply()` method that uses `xdebug_get_code_coverage()` and related functions. You said you added test code in the apply method and it isn't called. I'm not sure what the issue is. Are you sure you are pointing to the right server and code location? It is possible to run tests from the command line. Maybe you should try that. See code comments in [`lithium\console\command\Test`](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/lithium/blob/master/console/command/Test.php) or run `li3 test --help` for info on how to use the command-line test runner.

I can confirm on nginx I also have `/test/lithium/tests/cases/analysis/logger/adapter/CacheTest?filters[]=lithium\x5Ctest\x5Cfilter\x5CCoverage` in my access log. The `\x5C` is expected url encoding of the backslash character.